# Select Error syntax On VS2015 and maria db server

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, mariadb

I have a problem when I want to select results if attached image that shows the error message

[image]

Comment: What's the `@` sign use on the C# side ... and how is `con` created?  Also, in other Google example, there is not a `TableDirect` used with the query?

Comment: `@` is likely literal string sign here. And why it uses `CommandType.TableDirect` instead of `CommandType.Text`?